# Scroll one div over another

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get one div to overlap another div on scroll.

I have a [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelT/9MFDB/)

What I want to do is have the #wrapper overlap the #header on scroll.

Essentially the header is fixed then the wrapper overlays it.

Would a stickey element and a z-index do this?

Or is it a little more complicated.

I had something similar [here](http://www.cargocollective.com/btatest) but I cant get it to work on this fiddle (and yes I do change all the div names).

Note: The fade on scroll is something I'll tackle at a later date.

UPDATE:

```
html,
body
{
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
}
#header
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-size:100%;
}
#header img
{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    z-index:99;
}
#wrapper
{
    width:100%;
    background-color:lightgrey;
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
}
#outer
{
    margin:30px auto;
    padding-top:20px;
    position:relative;
    width:90%;
    height:1500px;
    background-color:red;
}
#inner
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:200px;
    height:250px;
    background-color:lightblue;
    top:20px
}​
```

HTML Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-UK">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DivTest2.css" />

        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function()

            {var header_w=$('#header').height(); ...});

    $('#wrapper').css('margin-top',header_w+'px');

$(window).resize(function()
{
    header_w=$('#header').height();

    $('#wrapper').css('margin-top',header_w+'px');
    });
});
});</script>
    <div id="header">
    <img src="http://davesizer.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/eva_jump.jpg" alt="Dog">
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>​

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just set position Fixed on Header Div.

Comment: @AdeelMughal fixed removes the header. Sachleen is the closest although not right as per my comment below.

Comment: so you want the wrapper on top or the header?? You have conflicting statements in your post and in the comment to sachleen

Comment: @MattHintzke on page load I want the grey #wrapper to stay below the #header – as it is at the moment. I always want it positioned below the header, even when the browser loses width. However, when a user scrolls the #wrapper div will overlap the header (go in front of) but the header will remain fixed to the original position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're okay with using jQuery:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var header_w=$('#header').height();

    $('#wrapper').css('margin-top',header_w+'px');

    $(window).resize(function()
    {
        header_w=$('#header').height();

        $('#wrapper').css('margin-top',header_w+'px');
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body
{
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
}
#header
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-size:100%;
}
#header img
{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    z-index:99;
}
#wrapper
{
    width:100%;
    background-color:lightgrey;
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
}
#outer
{
    margin:30px auto;
    padding-top:20px;
    position:relative;
    width:90%;
    height:1500px;
    background-color:red;
}
#inner
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:200px;
    height:250px;
    background-color:lightblue;
    top:20px
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9MFDB/4/)**

---

### Updated:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#wrapper').css('margin-top'header_w+'px');

    $(window).resize(function()
    {
        header_w=$('#header').height();

        $('#wrapper').css('margin-top',header_w+'px');
    });
});
```

Comment: @snuffin can I ask why that works on jsfiddle but not in sublime text 2 on preview? Code is: http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelT/zhzXB/. This is just how I see it in sublime – not how I'd set something in JSfiddle

Comment: `<div id="container">` should be `<div id="outer">`.

Comment: BTW, on jsFiddle you can set the framework (e.g. jQuery) in the left column. You don't have to add it separately.

Comment: @snuffin sorry this still isn't working. The image isn't there. I've updated my original post with all the code I'm seeing.

Comment: You'll have to use `$(document).ready(function(){var header_w=$('#header').height(); ...});`. Does this fix it?

Comment: @snuffin I've updated the HTML above. This still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly what you said, set the header's position to fixed. Then you add a top margin to wrapper to push it down initially. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9MFDB/1/)

Comment: this however, doesn't relate to the header, i want the wrapper to sit underneath header at all times. Your suggestion will prevent this from happening if the browser looses width. And the header has a height of auto which means it's difficult to resolve.